# Appending matricies into a single matrix with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a function in Python that returns a `numpy.mat` of shape `(100, 1)`. I am calling this function 4 times in a loop and would like to take the resulting 4 matricies and create a matrix of shape `(100, 4)`. I have looked for sometime at `numpy.append`, `numpy.concatenate`, and `numpy.insert` but have not been able to get this working.

Here is a short SSCCE of my issue

```
zeros = np.zeros(shape=(100, 4))
for i in range(1, 5):
    np.append(zeros, np.empty(shape=(100, 1)))
print(zeros)
```

Where `zeros` should results in a matrix of shape `(100, 4)` with "junk" values from each of the calls to `numpy.empty` and not all `0.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something along these lines -

```
zeros = np.zeros(shape=(100, 4))
for i in range(1, 5):
    data = np.random.rand(100,1) # func that returns (100,1) shaped array
    zeros[:,i-1] = data.ravel()
```

In place of `ravel()`, we could also use : `data[:,0]` or `np.squeeze(data)`, basic idea is to feed a `1D` array there, because the LHS `zeros[:,i-1]` expects a `1D` array there.

---

As an alternative, inside the loop, we could also do -

```
zeros[:,[i-1]] = data
```

Thus, with that list of column index `[i-1]` instead of `i-1`, we are keeping the dimensions into which `data` is to be assigned (keeps as 2D) and that allows us to feed in `data`, which is also `2D` without any change.